# EC2 (Beanstalk) crontab not updating via .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created the following file in .extensions/site_cron.config

```
container_commands:
  01_remove_old_cron_jobs:
    command: "crontab -r || exit 0"
  02_cronjobs:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/crontab | crontab"
    leader_only: true
```

My .ebextensions/crontab is:

```
0 23 * * * php /var/www/html/index.php cron publish_new
```

I took a snapshop of my logs from Beanstalk and see this:

```
2014-05-24 14:41:46,743 [DEBUG] Running command 01_remove_old_cron_jobs
2014-05-24 14:41:46,744 [DEBUG] Generating defaults for command 01_remove_old_cron_jobs
<<<

2014-05-24 14:41:46,857 [DEBUG] No test for command 01_remove_old_cron_jobs
2014-05-24 14:41:46,877 [INFO] Command 01_remove_old_cron_jobs succeeded
2014-05-24 14:41:46,877 [DEBUG] Command 01_remove_old_cron_jobs output: 
2014-05-24 14:41:46,878 [DEBUG] Running command 02_cronjobs
2014-05-24 14:41:46,878 [DEBUG] Generating defaults for command 02_cronjobs
<<<

2014-05-24 14:41:46,989 [DEBUG] Running test for command 02_cronjobs
2014-05-24 14:41:47,005 [DEBUG] Test command output: 
2014-05-24 14:41:47,006 [DEBUG] Test for command 02_cronjobs passed
2014-05-24 14:41:47,028 [INFO] Command 02_cronjobs succeeded
2014-05-24 14:41:47,029 [DEBUG] Command 02_cronjobs output: 
2014-05-24 14:41:47,029 [DEBUG] No services specified
```

Seems like everything went through OK and the instanced is in a green state. However, I do not see anything in `crontab -e` or in `/var/www/html/.ebextensions` -- what gives? How can I know that my cron jobs are in place and are ready to go?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to find my cron jobs.

I had to check with: `sudo crontab -l`

Previously I was using `crontab -l`

Not exactly sure why it show for sudo, but not for logged in user. I figured I was already root.

Anyways, since it in showing in that crontab, I am going to assume that they will run as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason if you install the jobs in the root crontab they don't run.
They have to be in the ec2-user crontab or they don't execute.